# Cosmodb query optimization

Tags: c#, sql, azure-cosmosdb

I am working in a MVC application, and the backend is Azure Cosmo db. I have large values in cosmo db. My application is based on graphical representaion of scores. So it's contains some filters based on the date or month or year. The issue is , when I filter the data based on month(fetch one month data) or year, it's take too much time for fetching the data.

```
`for (int i = 1; i < yearDays; i++)
{
 var dateofOccurance = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-yearDays + i);
 after = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-yearDays + i);

 string dateePrev = fp.DateofOccurance.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00";
 string dateeAfter = after.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T23:59:59";
 var query= "SELECT AVG(c.Score) as Score, AVG(c.Amount) as Amount  FROM c 
 WHERE c.DeviceId =" + Id + " AND c.DateTimeStamp > \'" + dateePrev + "\' AND c.DateTimeStamp < \'" + 
 dateeAfter + "\'";
  IEnumerable<Data> data= await GetItemsAsync(query: query);
}

   public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> GetItemsAsync(string queryString)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<Data>(new QueryDefinition(queryString));
            List<Data> results = new List<DataPoint>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();
                results.AddRange(response.ToList());
            }
            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

`

It's take too much time. Almost 80k records will fetch per month. Is any solution for increase the speed or get the data by one query?

Comment: How many RU/s do you have provisioned and how many does your query use? You might be getting throttled. Are the results in different partitions? What is your indexing strategy? My point is this is a broad topic that can't be answered simply.

Comment: There's a couple of possible causes/issues. What is the partition key for this collection? Queries should be in-partition for frequently run queries. Do you have a composite index defined? Queries with multiple properties in the where clause will benefit from composite Index. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-query-performance#filters-on-multiple-properties) Finally, if you are not doing in-partition queries, you may want to consider using Change Feed and pumping the data from this collection into one that can serve this query with an in-partition query.